# How to get the Value of Selected Radio Button in a Form using JQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have seen the jquery documents, stackoverflow and other forums, but this doesn't seem to work.

I have a radio button in a form, and I want to get the value of the selection.

If I remove the radio button from the form, I can get it by simply

```
var first_val = $('input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val();
```

But if I add it to to a form name=lifestyle

Any of these combinations don't work

I have a form named lifestyle
I have tried all the options in Chrome and it doesn't seem to work

Option 1

```
var first_val = $('#lifestyle input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val();
alert($('#lifestyle input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val());
```

Option 2

```
var first_val = $('form input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val(); 
alert($('form input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val());
```

Option 3

```
var first_val = $('#lifestyle input:radio[name=Question0]:checked', '#lifestyle').val();
alert($('#lifestyle input:radio[name=Question0]:checked','#lifestyle').val());
```

And so on..

I don't get the value and the alert says undefined.

Comment: can you post your markup

Comment: do you really need that long piece of selector.

Comment: Is the *name* of the form "lifestyle"? Your samples all reference it as if its ID is "lifestyle" (#lifestyle)? What 3nigma said :)

Comment: Are you saying the first selector shown in your question works if the element is not in a form but stops working if it is in a form? Because it should work either way unless there are multiple forms each containing elements with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If I remove the radio button from the form, I can get it by simply"

```
var first_val = $('input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val();
```

That selector should work regardless of whether the input belongs to a form or not. You'd only need to specify the form if there are multiple forms which each have inputs with the same name.

I would expect this to work:

```
$('form[name="lifestyle"] input:radio[name=Question0]:checked').val()
```

Option 1 doesn't work because your form has the *name* "lifestyle" but you are trying to use the *id* selector format with a "#". So:

```
//use
"form[name=lifestyle]"
// not
"#lifestyle"
```

Option 2 looks fine to me, assuming you have only one form element on the page.

Option 3 has the same problem with "#" selecting by id rather than name, but also by using the `$("selector", context)` syntax you are supposed to supply "A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context" (as explained [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), not a string, but in any case providing an element as context and then looking for that element within itself doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

> But if I add it to to a form name=lifestyle

change the selector like

```
var first_val = $("form[name='lifestyle']").find(":radio[name='Question0']:checked").val();
alert(first_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/NWEjg/2/

Hope it helps.